# Command line to install chocolatey packages on new machine from list of packages

Tags: command-line, windows-10, chocolatey

I have a list of chocolatey packages generated from the command below;

```
choco list --local-only
```

Is there a command line to install packages from the list onto a new machine?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: [How to get a list of packages from one machine and install in another with Chocolatey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167087/how-to-get-a-list-of-packages-from-one-machine-and-install-in-another-with-choco)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create the list of packages on machine A:

`choco list --idonly --localonly --limitoutput >chocolist.txt`

2. Copy the file "chocolist.txt" to machine B.
3. On machine B, start a PowerShell cmd window in Administrator mode.
4. Install the list of package on machine B:

`Get-Content chocolist.txt | foreach {choco upgrade -y --limitoutput $_}`