# How can users install multiple packages using Chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

I know that the `choco install` command can take multiple arguments like:

```
choco install package1 package2
```

This would install the packages one-by-one

I would like to know, however, if users can install multiple packages, specified in an external file, similar to the following:

```
choco install <external-file>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Chocolatey.org, you can use a simple `Packages.config` file.

More information here: https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandsinstall#packagesconfig

Quote from above link:

> This is a list of packages in an xml manifest for Chocolatey to install. This is like the packages.config that NuGet uses except it also adds other options and switches. This can also be the path to the packages.config file if it is not in the current working directory.

Comment: @Justin yes, you can check more using the link I sent. This StackOverflow question might help you more as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167087/how-to-get-a-list-of-packages-from-one-machine-and-install-in-another-with-choco

Comment: Just for completion: This is how you can install `choco install packages.config`